# How to deal with Facebook login as page

Tags: java, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Facebook has recently allowed pages to be created without any facebook users associated with them. Facebook also lets these unowned pages sign into applications. How should an application detect and handle this situation?

1. Sign out of facebook
2. [Create new facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php)
3. You have a new facebook page, with ID = 249578561746447
4. Sign into your facebook App.
5. Facebook auth callback returns the current user access token
6. **STRANGE** - User ID is = 100002923107961 (not 249578561746447??)
7. **ERROR** - "/me" connection returns "false"
8. **ERROR** - "/100002923107961" returns "false"
9. **Frustrating** [Facebook Auth Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) doesn't say this is possible
10. **Frustrating** There are no docs about this
11. **Frustrating** Reporting this issue to Faceboook gets blocked - [See here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/276712719014900?browse=search_4e8244816a5946a35798102)

Has anybody else even made a forray into this area yet? How should I go from a *magic user* with ID 100002923107961 to page with ID 249578561746447?

Comment: [Sparta Consulting](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Sparta-Consulting/249578561746447)? Might want to ask [WB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416449/) about that one :)

Comment: Uh oh. Please don't sue.

Answer (score 1):

If /me returns false, sign the user out with FB.logout and then show them a message saying they need to log in with a user account and not a page account.  Facebook is clear in that logged bug that this is by design.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have also thought about just hard disabling this feature. What if I want to let them sign in with a page account?